# new String() does not behave like an array like object

Tags: javascript

```
var nice = new String("ASH");
nice; //String {0: "A", 1: "S", 2: "H", length: 3, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "ASH"}
var reverseNice = Array.prototype.reverse.call(nice);
reverseNice.toString(); // "ASH"
```

whereas I was expecting `reverseNice` to be "HSA".

Comment: `new String()` will return only string object not primitive string. For that use "".

Comment: @hitman4890 it gives you something closer to how _JavaScript_ treats all _Strings_ internally (which is why we can access properties on them even though they're primitive values)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't make changes to `nice`, try it;

```
nice[0] = 'f';
nice[0]; // "A"
```

If you wanted to use the *Array* method, convert it to a true *Array* first

```
var reverseNice = Array.prototype.slice.call(nice).reverse(); // notice slice
reverseNice.join(''); // "HSA", notice `.join` not `.toString`
```

Comment: Yes, JavaScript strings are immutable. Also note that `new String()` returns an object, and `String()` returns a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
var nice = "ASH".split("");
nice; //Array {0: "A", 1: "S", 2: "H", length: 3}
var reverseNice = nice.reverse();
reverseNice.join("").toString(); // "HSA"
```

or just

```
var nice = "ASH".split("");
var reverseNice = nice.reverse().join("").toString();
```

Comment: If you use `split()` then this returns an Array object itself. Therefore you don't need `Array.prototype.reverse.call(nice);`. You just need `var reverseNice = nice.reverse()`. You also don't need `toString()` after the `join`, since `join` returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

use the `split` and `join` to convert type from `string` to `array` , just like this .

```
var nice = new String("ASH");
// create a string 


var result = Array.prototype.reverse.call(nice.split('')).join('');
// string can not use the reverse, 
// so we need split it and call the prototype function of Array ,
// and join the result in the end 

console.log(result)
```